# how can i hyperlink on table record

Tags: delphi

In delphi i manage hyperlink but i can not link any form of my project, how to link any form of project this is delphi. pls help me anyone

Comment: I think you've got some concepts mixed up: Hyperlink is an concept mostly used in Web development, while Delphi is mostly used for GUI development. You might want to edit your question and add a lot more details. Just explain what you'd like to do as you'd explain it to someone that doesn't know a thing about programming.

Comment: @Cosmin: `Ctrl+Click` on an identifier in the Delphi IDE code editor also mimics the Hyperlink concept. But Ctrl+Click on a `Form1` works fine here so I am not sure what this question is about...

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Delphi are you using? For which kind of form/component do you expect the Ctrl+Click to work?

Ctrl+Click won't work if the targeted unit has no source code available, or, dependant of the delphi IDE version you're using, if the unit is not in the main uses clauses of your application.